# Browse an ext4 filesystem and locate deleted files

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, partition, ext4

List the deleted files and access the data of deleted files.

I'm trying to read the file system block by block, but it showing the partition size 0.
Here is my python code

```
import os

BLOCK_SIZE = 4096  
DELETED_FILE_SIGNATURE = b'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' 
def list_deleted_files(partition_path):
    deleted_files = []

    partition_size = os.stat(partition_path).st_size

    with open(partition_path, 'rb') as f:

        num_blocks = partition_size // BLOCK_SIZE
        print(num_blocks)

        for block_number in range(num_blocks):
            block_data = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

            if DELETED_FILE_SIGNATURE in block_data:
                file_offset = block_data.index(DELETED_FILE_SIGNATURE)

                path_start = block_data.rfind(b'\0', 0, file_offset) + 1
                path_end = block_data.index(b'\0', file_offset)
                path = block_data[path_start:path_end].decode('utf-8')

                deleted_files.append(path)

    return deleted_files

partition_path = '/dev/nvme0n1p6'
deleted_files = list_deleted_files(partition_path)
print(deleted_files)
```

Output showing that number blocks is 0.
How to read partition correctly ?

Another method

```
import os

partition_path = '/dev/nvme0n1p6'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(partition_path):

for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
    
    if os.path.islink(file_path) and not os.path.exists(file_path):
        print(f"Deleted file found: {file_path}")
```

But it ended with 0 iterations of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `os.stat` but `os.statvfs`.

```
>>> os.stat('/dev/dm-2')
os.stat_result(st_mode=25008, st_ino=432, st_dev=5, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=995,
               st_size=0, st_atime=1679205488, st_mtime=1678984617, st_ctime=1678984617)

>>> os.statvfs('/dev/dm-2')
os.statvfs_result(f_bsize=4096, f_frsize=4096, f_blocks=4046122, f_bfree=4046122,
                  f_bavail=4046122, f_files=4046122, f_ffree=4045412, f_favail=4045412,
                  f_flag=4098, f_namemax=255)
```

You can use `f_blocks` and `f_bsize` to read the partition.

This is the same for command line:

```
[...]$ stat /dev/dm-2
  File: /dev/dm-2
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 0,5 Inode: 432         Links: 1     Device type: 254,2
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  995/    disk)
Access: 2023-03-19 06:58:08.718548364 +0100
Modify: 2023-03-16 17:36:57.311148772 +0100
Change: 2023-03-16 17:36:57.311148772 +0100
 Birth: 2023-03-16 17:36:53.131148947 +0100

[...]$ stat -f /dev/dm-2
  File: "/dev/dm-2"
    ID: 33d19ee4e765d8c4 Namelen: 255     Type: tmpfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 4046122    Free: 4046122    Available: 4046122
Inodes: Total: 4046122    Free: 4045412
```

Comment: How should I get number of blocks from this output ?

Comment: I think you can use `f_blocks`?

Comment: Reading a partition is not a trivial task. Use external library or use `dd` with subprocess module to get block data.

Comment: I tried the external libraries, but not getting the desired output. Can you help me to list the deleted files ?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Why using python for this task? You can use `TestDisk` to recover deleted files.

Comment: Actually I have to write code in any language to list deleted files and locate data of deleted files

Comment: So you can't use an external program?

Comment: I tried pytsk3 library but not able to list deleted files

Comment: I update the question with another method I tried but not getting the desired output